# How to aggregate two columns while creating a new column that counts the aggregation?

Tags: r, aggregate, unique, aggregate-functions, data-wrangling

I have this data

```
col1   col2
A      1
A      2
A      1
A      2
A      2
B      1
B      2
B      1
B      2
B      1
```

And I need to aggregate by col1 and col2, while creating col3, that counts:

```
col1   col2   col3
A      1      2
A      2      3
B      1      3
B      2      2
```

I tried aggregate function, but it requires me to use one of the existing columns to apply the function to and I couldn't add the third column.
I tried using unique across the two columns, but then I don't get col3.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   count(col1, col2, name = 'col3')
```